# laravel выборка или как получить массив

Tags: php, веб-программирование, laravel

Есть модель Friend на запроc:

```
Friend::all()->where("user" , "=" , $request->get("userid"))
```

получаю массив (точнее обьект json но по идеи это должен быть массив):

```
{
 "0": {
  "id": 1,
  "user": "farizid",
  "friend": "jamilyaid",
  "created_at": null,
  "updated_at": null
},
"2": {
  "id": 4,
  "user": "farizid",
  "friend": "heyriid",
  "created_at": null,
  "updated_at": null
  }
}
```

но для удобного парсинга требуется получить массив такого вида:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "user": "farizid",
    "friend": "jamilyaid",
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "user": "farizid",
    "friend": "heyriid",
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null
  }
]
```

Comment: `array_values((array) $json);` чем вам не угодил?

Comment: @ArchDemon а средствами канкретно ларавела нельзя? Чтобы при запросе готовый приходил

Comment: `->get()->values()` должно сработать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE: Важно!!!**

Когда первый раз отвечал, то не заметил, вы используете `->all()`, а потом -`>where(...)`. Это очень грубая ошибка. all возвращает не [Query/Builder](https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html), а уже коллекцию, [where тоже есть у коллекции](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-where). То есть Вы делаете запрос к бд на получение всех данных, но вам не нужны все.

Правильный запрос:

```
// get получает коллекцию моделей которые прошли запрос Query/Builder
Friend::where("user" , $request->userid)->get()
```

---

Если нужно получить массив из коллекции:

```
// ->values()->all()
Friend::where('user', $request->userid)->get()->values()->all();
```

Если нужно получить не массив, а коолекцию с которой можно дальше работать, то не надо `->all()`:

```
$values = Friend::where('user', $request->userid)->get()->values();
// теперь можно сделать, например, групировку по свойству user
$values->groupBy('user')
```

[Документация](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-values).

Также вместо $request->get("userid") можно использовать `$request->userid` и вместо `->where('user' , '=' , $request->userid)` можно`->where('user', $request->userid)`

Comment: Cпасибо. Очень помогли

Answer (score 0):

Метод коллекций [`values`](https://laravel.ru/docs/v5/collections#values) должен помочь:

```
Friend::all()->where("user" , "=" , $request->get("userid"))->get()->values();
```